# Azure Worker Role Error attaching the debugger

Tags: azure, .net-4.5, visual-studio-debugging, azure-worker-roles

I have created a simple cloud service and added a worker role under that. My cloud service is my start project and then pressed F5 to debug. It tries to open Emulators and then suddenly throws me below error.
I have Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Azure SDK 2.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue finally.

It was Firewall ..who was blocking remote debugging. 
Just go to Windows firewall - click on allow features - go to inbound rules - add VS 2012 devenv.exe in the list and that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Zone alarm turned it off is not enough. Add rule or uninstall it to try.